# Doesn't SQLAlchemy's db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow) create very tight coupling between the server and the Database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a personal project to learn Flask and web development in Python, creating a blog web-app.
I'm using SQLAlchemy to modelize the DB tables.

In case I had multiple programs connected to the same DB, a table modelized by a model, in my blog server, containing a column with a datetime like this:

```py
date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

would be very vulnerable by the other programs and each one would have to modelize this column like that again and again.

Wouldn't it be a better design choice to structure the schema of the table to have a `DEFAULT TIMESTAMP NOW` (or something like that) and let the ORM be more free to do whatever it wants with that column?

Before posting this question, I've also researched other ORMs of other languages and I see that almost all of them can do that.

Doesn't this way of adding `default`s to the model create very tight coupling and constrain the table for no reason? If not, please explain to me why this is wrong.